# Save and load Spark RDD from local binary file - minimal working example

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, rdd

I am working on a Spark app in which an RDD is first calculated, then need to be stored to disk, and then loaded again into Spark. To this end, I am looking for a minimal working example of saving an RDD to a local file and then loading it.

The file format is not suitable for text conversion, so `saveAsTextFile` won't fly.

The RDD can either be a plain RDD or Pair RDD, it is not crucial. The file format can be either of HDFS or not.

The example can be either in Java or Scala.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the type of the RDD you're trying to save?

Comment: For simplicity's sake let's assume pairs of integers, I couldn't even get this to work. Later, a pair of an integer and some serializeable object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as values in the RDD are serializable you can try to use `RDD.saveAsObjectFile` / `SparkContext.objectFile`:

```
case class Foobar(foo: Int, bar: Map[String, Int])
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(
    Foobar(1, Map("foo" -> 0)),
    Foobar(-1, Map("bar" -> 3))
))

rdd.saveAsObjectFile("foobar")
sc.objectFile[Foobar]("foobar")
```