# Binary Object data - persist into Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark

We have a binary object in our Java Spark code. We would like to save it as is into a Hadoop directory. How can we do this please. In plain java we do the following

```
File oldFile = new File("C:\\Documents\\obj.binary");
oldFile.delete();
File newFile = new File("C:\\Documents\\obj.binary");
FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
ObjectOutputStream Objso = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
Objso.writeObject(model);
Objso.flush();
Objso.close();
```

How can i do this in Hadoop (Spark Java) please.

We have hadoop 2.6.2, Spark 1.6.1

Thanks

Bala

Comment: http://hadoopinrealworld.com/writing-a-file-to-hdfs-java-program/

Comment: @pashaz. Thanks for your reply. What you have pointed to is to write from local system into HDFS. The requirement is, the object (model that i am referring in the question above) is built in the code and it is of a specific type. It is not in the local file system but in the Spark processing code

Comment: If binary object is present on driver node, it can be stored as second part of link above. If object present as DataFrame, or RDD, "saveAsObjectFile" can be used:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612071/save-and-load-spark-rdd-from-local-binary-file-minimal-working-example

For more info please look available Spark output formats

Comment: @pashaz thanks again. The object file is indeed in Driver. It was not a LIST, but could convert that and used the saveAsObjectFile. That worked like charm. Thanks so much for your help Pashaz..